# try to delete LF in python or notepad++ but cannot use "find&replace" to find it by "\n",

Tags: newline, eof

the picture is as the following: I don't know why I cannot locate the LF, so does CRLF!

According to the image, there is exactly LF there, but I cannot use notepad++'s find function by "\n" to really find it, so I cannot replace it with blank at all.

My goal is to delete the internal "LF" inside one entry.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1QxmUfK__dFbDR2MW5OZFZSekk/view

Comment: I think you need to double check the formatting on your question. And your Google Drive file is private.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1QxmUfK__dFbDR2MW5OZFZSekk/view?usp=sharing  Oh, this is the public link,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check extended mode. Currently your text editor is in "normal" mode.

You can change the mode with the option selects at the bottom of the search window.

When you check extended mode you can search on characters like \t\r\n and replace them. When you are in normal mode it will search for the actual string `'\n'`.